# Do I Need to create my own Node and Sync it with the Main Network in order to create Accounts via Web3?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, nodes

As my Question title states, I would like to know, If it's a requirement to run my own hosted Geth Node synched with the Main-Network in order to use web3.js (localhost Node?) to create accounts?

**Or** is it possible to "*point*" **web3** with the Main Network as a provider? and with this reference, create accounts for example?

If the latter is possible, Could you please show me an example?

-Kind Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating accounts is just picking a large random number. It can certainly be done offline and without a node to connect to.

E.g., using [`ethereumjs-wallet`](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-wallet):

```
> const key = require('ethereumjs-wallet').generate();
undefined
> key.getAddress().toString('hex')
'eac913b60f61e566910b02c7bf6fd47ef115875c'
> key.getPrivateKey().toString('hex')
'62e1499a16be79fcd87e0fa748a6735a12e7252568942a8226179c02d5a454ac'
```

Comment: Interesting, May I ask a follow up question? How then, do you "integrate" that Account into the Main-Net?

Comment: A simplified view of Ethereum is that it's a distributed mapping of addresses to balances. (E.g. "`0x123` owns 3 ether," "`0x987` owns 1 ether," etc.) Anything not in the map owns 0 ether. So the account I just created above has 0 ether. If you send it 1 ether, it will have 1 ether, even though I've never done anything with the account. So there's no explicit "creation" step that involves the network. You'll need to talk to the network only when you need to make a transaction (using your account's private key).

Comment: Awesome! That's a fantastic lesson, Thank you. May I point out however, that what I need to know the most is How to use web3 with the Main-Network as a Provider, Do you happen to know how to do that? (As I'd prefer NOT to run my own Node).

Comment: Yes, you can use any public node. The most popular is Infura.io, and even more popular is using that via MetaMask. (It's the default in MetaMask.) Perhaps this blog post of mine will help: https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2017/12/13/building-decentralized-apps-with-ethereum-and-javascript/

Comment: Hey, since it's very rare to randomly find a Guru, May I ask a final one? When a contract is deployed in the Main-Net, is there a way (using web3) to unlock an account other than using the password? I Guess that this is the biggest Doubt I have as a beginner, and now I'm more puzzled since your 'offline' sample does not involve entering a password At All. Thank you!

Comment: To use an account, you just need the private key. Most tools (MetaMask, Geth, Mist) encrypt the private key with a password, but it doesn't have to work that way. I'm not sure I can give more info without understanding the scenario better; sorry!